# MapBox Marker Size on Zoom (ios sdk)

Tags: ios, zooming, mapbox, marker

I'm trying to change the size of the marker image during a zoom event, so the image scales nicely while pinching/zooming.

I can't find anywhere how to do this, the closest I have come is to resize the marker image after the zoom event is completed (when the zoom level changes)

It would look a lot nicer if it would resize during the zoom event instead of after.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `RMMapLayer` directly (`RMMarker`'s superclass) which should scale when zoomed. `RMShape` and `RMCircle` are also a good, albeit not directly related, models for this since they represent shapes that "stick" to the map instead of points that don't scale. But the short answer is there is not built-in functionality for this.

Comment: Using a shape would most likely size the image relational to the zoom right? I would like to have control over the actual size. (Only resizing a little bit so markers close to each other won't overlap). Any chance this functionality can be added?